# The overflow:hidden is not working in my slideshow project

Tags: html, css, overflow

I'm trying to create a slideshow app using CSS animations. I have a main container with class `container` that wraps everything that is on my website. It has two div elements - one for the main page with button that when it is clicked it takes you to the image slideshow (the second div element).

I'm asking for help with slideshow itself (divs with class `banner` set to `display: none` right now). I set an animation for `.slideshow-wrapper` to change its `left` property so the images inside it can slide. They are set to be next to each other with `display: flex` and `flex-direct: column` in `.slideshow-wrapper` CSS rule. Also each one of the slideshow-wrapper elements have set width and height to 100% of viewport.

Everything is working good but I don't want a user of the slideshow page to be able to scroll between images. When I set `overflow: hidden` on `.container` it hasn't worked, and I don't understand why.

Also when I tried to fight with this problem by setting `overflow: hidden` in `.slideshow-wrapper` it hasn't helped — it slides from first image to blank white space. Why is that happening?

Here is the HTML and CSS code:

```css
.container {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.banner {
  display: none;
}

.slideshow-wrapper {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  animation: slideAnim 24s infinite;
}

@keyframes slideAnim {
  0% {
    left: 0
  }
  14% {
    left: 0
  }
  16% {
    left: -100vw
  }
  31% {
    left: -100vw
  }
  33% {
    left: -200vw
  }
  48% {
    left: -200vw
  }
  50% {
    left: -300vw
  }
  64% {
    left: -300vw
  }
  66% {
    left: -200vw
  }
  82% {
    left: -100vw
  }
  100% {
    left: 0%
  }
}

.slide {
  height: 100vh;
  min-width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="banner">
    <!-- main page with button -->
  </div>

  <div class="slideshow-wrapper">
    <div class="slide">
      <!-- content of the slide -->
    </div>

    <div class="slide">
      <!-- content of the slide -->
    </div>

    <div class="slide">
      <!-- content of the slide -->
    </div>

    <div class="slide">
      <!-- content of the slide -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you sure the body tag has not padding or margin???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't work because yout a position absolute to the slide show wrapper you can instead take off that position set and make change its padding left from 0 to minus whatever you want an make overflow hidden to the container

Answer (score 0):

try to remove position absolute and set a fixed width and height on wrraper